# iOS Get timestamp without hours and minutes and seconds

Tags: ios, iphone

```
 NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
 [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
 NSString *theDate = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];
 time_t unixTime = (time_t) [date timeIntervalSince1970];
```

i need unixTime without hours, minutes and seconds

Comment: What do you mean by "without hours, minutes and seconds"? Do you mean the number of seconds discounting all time passed in the current day? So basically until midnight that just passed?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to extract the significant date components from the original date

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];

NSCalendar *gregorianCalendar = [NSCalendar calendarWithIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];

NSDateComponents *componentsDate = [gregorianCalendar components:NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitDay fromDate:date];
```

And then, build a new date with them

```
NSDateComponents *toDateComponents = [NSDateComponents new];
[toDateComponents setYear:[componentsDate year]];
[toDateComponents setMonth:[componentsDate month]];
[toDateComponents setDay:[componentsDate day]];
[toDateComponents setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];

NSDate *toDate = [gregorianCalendar dateFromComponents:toDateComponents];
```

To finally, get the time interval

```
NSTimeInterval toDateTimeInterval = [toDate timeIntervalSince1970];
```

Answer (score 0):

Or coming at it from the other direction, and in Swift:

```
// Get the current date and time
let theDate = NSDate()

// Get the current hours, minutes and seconds from "now"
let theCalendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let theComponents = theCalendar.components(.CalendarUnitHour | .CalendarUnitMinute | .CalendarUnitSecond, fromDate: theDate)

// Construct a new time, the equivalent number of seconds earlier than "now". This is effectively midnight that passed
let theCorrectedDate = NSDate( timeInterval: -(NSTimeInterval)((theComponents.hour * 3600) + (theComponents.minute * 60) + theComponents.second), sinceDate: theDate )

// And that gives you the unix time you want
let theUnixTime = theCorrectedDate.timeIntervalSince1970
```